Why .libPaths update in R but not in Rstudio?
I made a copy of R from C: drive in windows to a usb stick together with a copy of Rstudio.
I don't know why, but when I run .libPaths() inside R using the usb stick it gives me two paths, one is the local windows AppData and the other is the path of library folder inside the usb stick. Rstudio otherwise also shows two paths but one is the C: drive path from where it came and the other is the AppData path. Because of that when I try to load some library like library(data.table) in Rstudio it gives an error and when I run it inside R it loads the library normally.
Anyone know why default R update automatically .libPaths() when you make a copy of R folder to a different one and Rstudio doesn't? Is there a way to make it auto update like normal R?

I think Rstudio sets up its own environment variable set.
